# Dojo can't programmatically concatenate djits?

Tags: javascript, dojo

With this code:

```
var d = new dijit.Dialog({
    title: "Programatic Dialog Creation",
    style: "width: 300px",
});
var button1 = new dijit.form.Button({'label': 'one', 'onClick': function () {
        alert('one')
}});

var button2 = new dijit.form.Button({'label': 'two', 'onClick': function () {
        alert('two');
}});
d.attr("content", button1 + ' | ' + button2);
d.show();
```

Expected result: A dialog with with two buttons inside

Actual result: A dialog with the text

> [Widget dijit.form.Button, dijit_form_Button_4] | [Widget dijit.form.Button, dijit_form_Button_5]

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to accomplish this task?
I've tried dojo.place and dojo.query with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing up Dijit objects, DOM nodes and strings.

The corrent way to place Dijits into Dialog or any container widget is:

```
dojo.place(button1.domNode, d.containerNode);
dojo.place(button2.domNode, d.containerNode);
d.show();
```

Or you can call placeAt() method when creating Dijit object:

```
var button1 = new dijit.form.Button({'label': 'one', 'onClick': function () {
    alert('one')
}}).placeAt(d.containerNode);
```

You got your result because what basically happens is

```
d.attr("content", button1.toString() + '|' + button2.toString());
```

Also note inserting strings is possible this way:

```
var button1Html = dojo.create("div").appendChild(button1.domNode).parentNode.innerHTML;
var button2Html = dojo.create("div").appendChild(button2.domNode).parentNode.innerHTML;
d.set("content", button1Html + "|" + button2Html);
```

but it won't work, because it creates new DOM nodes that are not referenced in Dijit objects (buttons), so your events won't fire.

Comment: This is one of the things that confused me for too long as well, since it's barely mentioned anywhere on the official docs. What it comes down to is, you place the buttons' domNode into the dialog's containerNode. You can do that just like you would for any other two DOM nodes.

Comment: When I was using the placeAt() function the part I was missing was the .containerNode
Thank you for the thorough explanation.