# reset() with dojo ComboBox

Tags: html, combobox, dojo, reset, dom-events

I would like to reset a dojo ComboBox after a (separate) combobox onchange event.  But when I try to do this manually in JS, I get an error.  What am I doing wrong here?

error:

> TypeError: dojo.byId("boroughSelect").reset is not a function (Firebug)

HTML:

```
       <select id="layerSelect" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox"autoComplete="true" value="Selecy Layer"
                   forceValidOption="false" class="comboBoxClass" onchange="setFlag(this)" >

                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
                <option>option3</option>

       </select>
```

JS:

```
function setFlag(selItem)

{
    dojo.byId("boroughSelect").reset();

}
```

Comment: Are your core dojo files loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain a reference to `dijit` instance, not to `DOMNode`, therefore use `dijit.byId()` instead of `dojo.byId()`:

```
dijit.byId("boroughSelect").reset();
```

For more detail, please see my answer to [Dojo can't programmatically concatenate dijits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454552/dojo-cant-programmatically-concatenate-djits/8455984#8455984)

Comment: thanks, yes I saw this on the Dojo list as well...I shoulda figured that one out...Thanks for help.

Comment: In addition, you may want to clear the onchange handler before invoking reset so as to avoid sending an Ajax request you may have configured.