# dojo/form/select onchange event not working for me in dojo 1.8

Tags: dojo

I am trying out dojotoolkit 1.8 and cant figure out how to hook up an onchange event for a dojo/form/select

Nothing happens with this

```
require(["dojo/dom","dojo/on"], function(dom,on){
   on(dom.byId("myselect"),"change",function (evt){
         alert("myselect_event");

});
```

If instead, the following hook into click works:

```
on(dom.byId("myselect"),"click",function (evt){
```

- but i want to capture the value after user clicks and changes

I am sure it is simpler than going back to Plain ol javascript onChange...

Thx

Comment: You are mixing up Dijit objects and DOM nodes. @nozzleman's solution should work. If you would like to find out more, have a look at [Dojo can't programatically concatenate dijits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454552/dojo-cant-programmatically-concatenate-djits/8455984#8455984)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    var select = dijit.byId('myselect');

    select.on('change', function(evt) {
        alert('myselect_event');
    });
```

I've seen this in the reference-guide multiple times, eg [in the dijit/form/select' s reference-guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/Select.html) at *'A Select Fed By A Store'*.

Maybe it even returnes the `handle`, i haven't looked this up so far. But i guess it should work.

**EDIT:**

Considering @phusick's comment, i want to add, that you could also simply change the `"change"` to `"onChange"` or the `dom` to `dijit` within calling `on(...)`

Comment: Well, we are glad beeing able to help you out! How about accepting a answer then? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Following in the footsteps of @nozzleman's answer try

```
var select = registry.byId('myselect');

select.on('change', function(evt) {
    alert('myselect_event');
});
```

If you use `on` instead of `connect` then you don't have to write `onChange`, you can simply write `change`.

Comment: Thx - additional clarification - is using element.on construct better than using on (domnode,"event") or is it just 2 ways of saying the same thing....

Comment: I think the former is better for 2 reasons. First, it follows the API of other JS frameworks (like jQuery) and second, it might just become native in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above answers do a dijit.ById to find the correct element and then register the 'onItemClick' event.

creating the select dropdown programatically appends a _menu to whatever node you create the select items so 'search' becomes 'search_menu' on a page init you can do the following:

```
  dojo.connect(dijit.byId('search_menu'),'onItemClick',function(){
        //console.log("search menu");
        doSearch('recreation');
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're trying to access the Dijit using DOM. Also, the parameter to the anonymous function for the "change" event is the **value** selected by the user, not the event itself.

Here's your code modified to access the Dijit and process the "change" event:

```
require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/on"], function(registry, on) {
   on(registry.byId("myselect"), "change", function (value) {
         alert("change_event.value = " + value);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I recently ran into the issue. Hopefully my answer will help some poor soul maintaining some legacy code. The answer is for combobox but worked for select as well -

onChange not sufficient to trigger query from Dojo Combobox. Need to attach listener to dropdown items.

```
select.dropDown.on("itemClick", function(dijit, event) {
var node = dijit.domNode;
console.log(domAttr.get(node, "data-info-attribute"));
// or
console.log(node.dataset.infoAttribute);
});
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422155/4564016